# If @RequestParameter is given, filter by it's value, if not do nothing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, functional-programming

I'm trying to use @RequestParam, and if the value is given it should filter from all items found in the database by this parameter, if not it should do nothing.  I would also like to ask if functional programming is a good use here.

This is my Car class:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long Id;

    private int yearOfProduction;
    private int price;
    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer")
    private Customer customer;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(int yearOfProduction, int price, String color, String brand, String model) {
        this.yearOfProduction = yearOfProduction;
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

This is the Controller where I set the parameters to ask for:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Car> getCars(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer minPrice,
                         @RequestParam(required = false) Integer maxPrice,
                         @RequestParam(required = false) String model){

    return carService.getCars(minPrice, maxPrice, model);
}
```

This is Car Service and what I would like to do:

```
public List<Car> getCars(Integer minPrice, Integer maxPrice, String model) {
    return carRepository
            .findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(car ->
                      //if minPrice exists
                                car.getPrice() >= minPrice
                                 &&
                       //if maxPrice exists
                                 car.getPrice() <= maxPrice
                                 &&
                       //if model exists
                                 car.getModel().equals(model))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I could set `@RequestParam (defaultValue = "something")` in controller, but it's problematic since I don't know what are the default values for "model" field, because every Car has a different model, and still I have to filter items by default values, and it's not needed since I don't want to do anything with that if it's not given.

I was also trying to pass `Optional<>` as the parameters and then check every parameter with if statement and ifPresent() method in filter function, but I don't how how to bring it together.

Comment: One simple rule to follow, don't do something in your code the database does it better than you. Filtering and sorting are better handled by the database.

Comment: @b.GHILAS So you suggest to create for example 3 SQL queries in repository, then write 3 if statements in getCars() function, check if parameter exists and inside them execute a proper function ? Cause I don't know how to make all configurations of given parameters work in these queries, because some of them have a common elements for sure. Could you explain it in more details please?

Comment: Update your question and provide the entity Car, I assume you want to get all the cars by default, and if there's any request params filter by it. If is this what you want, it's easy to accomplish with JPA.

Comment: @b.GHILAS I updated it, and yes that is exacly what  I want to do.

Comment: @b.GHILAS is correct.  Don't fetch all the values and filter in your service. Set default values to `*` and pass the values to your `@Repository` for use in a parameterized query (to avoid SQL injection attacks).

Comment: Just do a findAll with example, and put your params in the example if they are null the query will ignore them, if not it will add the where clause. just look up findAll(Example example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a jpa query like this (in your car repository):

```
@Query("select c from Car c where (?1 is null or c.price >= ?1) and (?2 is null or c.price <= ?2) and (?3 is null or c.model = ?3)")
List<Car> getCars(Integer minPrice, Integer maxPrice, String model);
```

and then call it from your `CarService`:

```
public List<Car> getCars(Integer minPrice, Integer maxPrice, String model) {
   return carRepository.getCars(minPrice, maxPrice, model);
}
```

---

One way to circumvent cast problem in postgresql, is to use default values for the params. Say you set 0 as default value for min price and max price and empty string for model.

```
@Query("select c from Car c where (?1 = 0 or c.price >= ?1) and (?2 = 0 or c.price <= ?2) and (?3 = '' or c.model = ?3)")
List<Car> getCars(Integer minPrice, Integer maxPrice, String model);
```

And in your controller:

```
@RequestParam(defaultValue="") String model
@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") Integer minPrice
@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") Integer maxPrice
```

Comment: Unfortunetely I'am getting error: ,,ERROR: operator does not exist: integer >= bytea Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: It works fine now, it shows no errors, but when I sent request it returned response code 200 but I got no results (no cars have been displayed)

Comment: @77jt777 did you configure the default values well, what's the generated query ?

Comment: This is the only thing I get in console:  Hibernate:
    select
        car0_.id as id1_0_,
        car0_.brand as brand2_0_,
        car0_.color as color3_0_,
        car0_.customer as customer7_0_,
        car0_.model as model4_0_,
        car0_.price as price5_0_,
        car0_.year_of_production as year_of_6_0_ 
    from
        cars car0_ 
    where
        (
            ?=0 
            or car0_.price>=?
        ) 
        and (
            ?=0 
            or car0_.price<=?
        ) 
        and (
            ?='' 
            or car0_.model=?
        )

Comment: @77jt777 are you sure that you configured the default values (minPrice and maxPrice to 0) and model to empty string ?

Comment: I missplaced 0 with empty string so nevermind! Everything works great, sorry for bothering you and thank you very much for your help and attention!

Comment: @77jt777 no problem, another way to do this is using Jpa Specification (google it, It will help you create queries with multiple filters easily)

Comment: Okay, surely I will, thank you once again!